# Quantum Hamiltonian of EM Fields - Error in Gasiorowicz?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

In Section 16-2 of Gasiorowicz' *Quantum Physics: Third Edition* Gasiorowicz gives the momentum-component of the Hamiltonian of an election in an EM field as

$ \frac{1}{2m_e} [-i\hbar \nabla + eA]^2 $

where $ A $ is the EM Vector Potential.

Later, Gasiorowicz expands this term, and writes the momentum-component as

$ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}\nabla^2 -\frac{ie\hbar}{m_e}(A\cdot\nabla) - \frac{ie\hbar}{m_e}(\nabla \cdot A) + \frac{e^2}{2m_e}A^2 $

Immediately, observed that the first and last term have a factor of $1/2$ while the two middle terms do not. What happened to the factor of $ 1/2 $ for the two middle terms--is there something I missed? Or is there some error with Gasiorowicz calculation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is a little annoying here. Setting $\hbar = e = m = 1$, we have
$$\frac12 (- i \nabla + A)^2 = \frac12 (- i \partial_i + A_i)^2$$
and the cross-terms are
$$- \frac{i}{2} \partial_i A_i - \frac{i}{2}A_i \partial_i.$$
The derivative $\partial_i$ acts on everything to its right, so by considering how everything would act on a wavefunction, we conclude 
$$\partial_i A_i = A_i \partial_i + (\partial_i A_i)$$
where on the second term on the right, the $\partial_i$ only acts on $A_i$. Applying this to the first cross-term,
$$- i A_i \partial_i - \frac{i}{2} (\partial_i A_i) = - i A \cdot \nabla - \frac{i}{2} (\nabla \cdot A).$$
So one of the terms is missing a factor of $1/2$. I would bet the reason Gasiorowicz has this error is that shortly afterward, he probably sets $\nabla \cdot A = 0$, so it never makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification; I was a bit lazy with my operators, and mistakenly thought $ \nabla \cdot (A \psi ) = ( \nabla \cdot A) \psi $ , when actually $  \nabla \cdot (A \psi ) = ( \nabla \cdot A) \psi + (A \cdot \nabla ) \psi $, because of the product rule.